# Trying to make a recursive function in OCaml

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

So I have this while loop concept that I'd like to translate into an OCaml recursion:

Pseudocode:

```
n = read integer from stdin
m = 1
while m*(m+1)/2 < n
    m = m + 1
print m
```

My attempt in OCaml:

```
let n = int_of_string (input_line stdin) in

let rec get_ans m n =
    if m*(m+1)/2 < n then get_ans (m + 1) n else m;;

print_endline get_ans 1 n;
```

However I am just getting "syntax error" on the long function line without any detail as to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `in` to link toplevel declarations. The reason you're getting an error at `;;` rather than at `in` is that it expects `;;` to be `in <valid expression>`. You also have some problems with missing or superfluous parentheses. Removing the first `in` would work:

```
let n = int_of_string (input_line stdin);;

let rec get_ans m n =
    if m*(m+1)/2 < n then get_ans (m + 1) n else m;;

print_endline (string_of_int (get_ans 1 n));
```

Alternatively, using `in` after the second let binding as well would make it a valid expression:

```
let n = int_of_string (input_line stdin) in
let rec get_ans m n =
  if m*(m+1)/2 < n then get_ans (m + 1) n else m in

print_endline (string_of_int (get_ans 1 n))
```

But in that case a leading `let () =` is inferred to make it a valid toplevel declaration.

Comment: Which of the two is the preferred approach? I'm new to OCaml and so I don't fully understand the double-;; vs. the in-thing and all that - which should I be sticking with?

Comment: Also why does the first example end in one `;` as opposed to two `;;`?

Comment: Both forms are fine if you're just playing around. In a real world project you probably shouldn't read from stdin into a global variable however. It's then conventional to have define a kind of `main` function with `let () = let n = ... in print_endline ...` but keep the `get_ans` function as a top level declaration

Comment: `;;` is used to separate toplevel declarations (but can be skipped if you have a sequence of let bindings, since it can then be inferred). `;` is used to sequence expressions. `<expression>;` is equivalent to `let _ = <expression> in`. It will ignore the result and will cause a warning if the expression does not return unit. In this case it's unnecessary but causes no harm.